# Identifying the color in Image

Tags: image-processing, color

This has mad me Crazy for a while Can any one please Help me solving this 
this is the Image that I am working on .
Basically this image is made up of 98 different color patches
7 patch on each level 
and there are 14 such level

I want to get the colour of each patch on each level in something like an array
like this

```
colorPatch={{#524,#521,#124,#897,#365,#489,#546},   -->Level 1
            {#124,#524,#897,#365,#546,#514,#687},   -->Level2
            .
            .}                                   -->nth Level
```

this is what i did till now

```
s = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubuPp.jpg"];
p = ImagePartition[s, {50, 69}]
```

[image]

Comment: So you want the colour of each tiles of `p`?

Comment: Yes I want to identify the color of each tiles in P I am trying to use DominantColors[image, n] but my implentation is not correct

Comment: An other question is, do you want the colours of the icons on the some tiles?

Comment: No I don't want to find the color of that icon those will be used latter on to group tiles in P based on the icon..but for now just to find the color of the tiles

Comment: Using interpunction can work wonders for the readibility of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just take the value of the pixel in the middle of the tile, if you want the mean value of the whole tile just use `Mean@Flatten[ImageData[#], 1] & /@ p`.

```
s = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubuPp.jpg"];
p = Flatten[ImagePartition[s, {50, 69}], 1]
colors = PixelValue[#, .5*ImageDimensions@#] & /@ p;
GraphicsRow@{p[[1]], Graphics[{RGBColor@colors[[1]], Disk[]}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[`DominantColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DominantColors.html) is a *v9* feature, so I can not check what I'm doing right now but

```
DominantColors[#, 5] & /@ p
```

should give you the `5` first dominant colours in each tiles.

---

If you want to preserve the structure of `p`:

```
p = ImagePartition[s, {50, 69}];
dom = DominantColors[#, 5] &;
colors = Map[dom, p, {2}]
```

should give you the `5` first dominant colours in each tiles, with `Dimensions@colors === Dimensions@p`.

Comment: Can you please Explain me according to syntax for DominantColors is  DominantColors[image, n] but what is the meaning of # &/a in your code

Comment: `/@` is the shorthand of `Map` so the function `DominantColors[#, 5]` is mapped through all the elements of `p`.

Comment: Simpler way to preserve the structure: `Map[PixelValue[#, .5*ImageDimensions@#] &, p, {2}]`

Comment: @RahulNarain Thank you :) I knew there was something but I never remember the `Map[,{2}]` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Guy for your assistance and guidance :D